# How To Re-Create Gmail Storage Size Javascript Counter?

Tags: php, javascript, gmail, counter

I'm sure this is incredibly simple for somebody, but I am failing to grasp the concept.

How does one re-create a gmail storage size styled counter as shown on the gmail.com homepage on their own website?

When you visit the gmail.com site, a storage size counter starts at number X (according to the official time?) and increases a certain (miniscule) amount every second.

When you refresh the page, the number X has been updated (increased) and continues to increase a certain amount every second still.

Is a storage engine like MySQL needed at all? Or simply a php date measurement with some javascript?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google will take an average of how much extra space is added daily, or whatever, and use that to get JavaScript to increment a counter by a certain amount. You are indeed correct in saying that PHP sets the starting number based on the time the page was requested. It's not live, unfortunately - that would be cool.

James